# Require SVGs in react-native

Tags: javascript, svg, react-native

I created a simple component that displays SVG images inside a `WebView`. This works nicely when I fetch the SVG from a remote server. However, I would like to include the SVG in my bundle and require it from my component.
Using `require('image.svg')` results in a *Unable to resolve module* error message.

Comment: Save the svg file as .txt entension, or maybe .xml

Comment: @kar This gives me the same error. What I could do is inline the SVG as string in a js file: `export default '<svg>...';`, but I would prefer to include the SVG file as it is and not convert it to JS.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and noticed that the path displayed in the error wasn't quite right. I had to do `require('./image.svg')` or if you put it in a separate folder, say assets, it would be `require('./assets/image.svg')`. This relative path would have to be determined from whichever file you are in of course. So if you are in `index.ios.js` and wanted to require the image file with the following folder structure:

`.
├── index.ios.js
└── assets
    ├── image.svg
    └── image2.png`

use `require('./assets/image.svg')`. Hope this helps!

Comment: The exact error message I get is: `Unable to resolve module ../images/image.svg from [...]: Invalid directory [...]`. However the path shown in the error message is correct. Also, it works for png-images.

Comment: This might be an issue with how the SVG is getting passed in when you are requiring it versus fetching it from the server. Check out this [PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/542) found on the first answer to [this stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289178/react-native-and-svgcode-sample) on ways to put your SVG in a WebView.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a little late to answer but this works fine

just add your `.svg` containing folder to `package.json` asset like blew

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./images" // <--- add your image folder here
    ]
  }
```

now your `.svg` file is accessible in `require('./images/your_svg_file.svg')`

then don't forget to try this command `react-native link`